# Autowire Getting null whilw declare inside mockito test class at run time

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, spring-boot-test

> I want to test my function what I created in my service class, when I
> declare service class inside test class with the help of @Autowired
> annotation It gives me null value. For your reference I post my codes
> what I do in my project.

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RepGroupServiceImplTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private RepGroupServiceImpl repGroupServiceImpl;
    
    @MockBean
    private RepGroupManufacturerRepository repGroupManufacturerRepository;
    @MockBean
    private RepGroupRetailerRepository repgroupRetailerRepository;
    
    @Test
    public void buyerAccessRequestTest(){
        SearchRequest request = getSearchRequest();
        Set<String> manufactureIDset= new HashSet<String>();
        manufactureIDset.add("M1002415");
        if (repGroupServiceImpl == null) {
            System.out.println("Hey I am getting null value");
        } else {
           System.out.println("Hey I am not null");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        Set<String> searchRequest = repGroupServiceImpl.buyerAccessRequest(request, manufactureIDset);
        
    }

    private SearchRequest getSearchRequest() {
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
            searchRequest.setRepGroupID("R2132");
            searchRequest.setRetailerID("B364124");
            searchRequest.setRetailerStatus("ACTIVE");
            searchRequest.setActive(null);
            return searchRequest;
    }
```

> my repGroupServiceImpl gives null value ,Autowire not working
> properly.

Comment: Side note: consider to use JUnit 5

Comment: I already Try Junit5 but getting same issue

Comment: Is the implementation of your service being scanned by the component scan?